# SQL Join 3 tables return where record is not matched in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server : trying to join 3 tables (one table is duplicated), people and appointments. I want to return all people where they have appointment of type A, but have not had an appointment of type B or C.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first, p.last
FROM people p
JOIN appt a ON a.pkid = p.pkid
JOIN appt s ON s.pkid = p.pkid 
WHERE
    a.kept = 'SomeValue'
    AND a.appt_type = '9999999' 
    AND (s.appt_type <> '88888888' OR s.appt_type <> '8888888888')
```

Where am I getting confused, do I have to do a select into, or do I need a different type of join?

Comment: I don't see any A/B/C appt types but did you mean to use `s.event_id`

Comment: @dbmitch yes... thank you for pointing out, i corrected the original question.

Comment: If yoiu want all condiftions to be true - Change the `OR` to `AND`(and you don't need the brackets but they won't hurt you)

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from people p
where exists (select 1
              from appt a
              where a.pkid = p.pkid and a.kept = true and
                    a.appt_type = '9999999'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from appt s
                  where s.pkid = p.pkid and
                        s.appt_type in ('88888888', '8888888888')
                 );
```

Note: I kept the logic the same as in your question, but SQL Server doesn't recognize `true`.

Comment: When using exists and not exists I can't select from the appointments tables, (ex: select a.appt_type); do i have to do a join to be able to select it?

Comment: @DDulla . . . Your `select` clause does not have any columns from `appt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first, p.last
FROM people p
JOIN appt a ON a.pkid = p.pkid
WHERE a.kept = true 
AND a.appt_type='9999999' 
AND
not exists ( select 1 from appt s 
              where s.pkid = p.pkid  
                AND ( s.appt_type = '88888888' OR 
              s.event_id = '8888888888')
```

You did not give the requirement clearly. But you are looking at something like this.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first, p.last
FROM people p
JOIN appt a ON a.pkid = p.pkid
left JOIN appt s ON s.pkid = p.pkid and (s.appt_type = '88888888' OR s.event_id = '8888888888')
WHERE
a.kept = true AND a.appt_type='9999999' AND
 s.event_id is null
```